# A class cannot contain operator functions for an inner defined enum?

Tags: c++, class, methods, enums, operator-overloading

I've created a class with an enum defined in it. I also wanted to define some operators for the enum like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        enum MyEnum { CONSTA, CONSTB, CONSTC };
        // ...
        MyEnum& operator++(MyEnum& orig);
        MyEnum operator++(MyEnum& orig, int);
        // ...
}
```

For this code, gcc gives the following error message:

```
.../MyClass.h|10|error: postfix ‘MyClass::MyEnum& MyClass::operator++(MyClass::MyEnum&)’ must take ‘int’ as its argument
.../MyClass.h|11|error: ‘MyClass::MyEnum MyClass::operator++(MyClass::MyEnum&, int)’ must take either zero or one argument
```

Which means, that the compiler believes that I want to write an operator for MyClass, not for MyEnum. So it wants me to reduce the arguments.

My question is:

Can a class in some way contain operator functions for something else than itself (e.g. for an inner type) or should I move those functions outside of MyClass?

Comment: Just omit the `MyEnum& orig` parameters for the operator aignature declarations.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ If I weren't clear enough: I don't want to write operators for `MyClass`, I want to write one for `MyEnum`. I i omitted the `MyEnum& orig` parameter, how would I refer to the enum variable I want to increment from inside the function?

Comment: Tried overloading non class member operators?

Comment: `operator++` for class or enum `A` can't be a member of class `B`. It can be a member of class `A` (won't work for enums, of course), or a non-member function at namespace scope. [Working example](http://ideone.com/AQDXDK)

Comment: @dyp `friend` is a non-member at namespace scope, really. It's a quirk of the syntax that it can be defined in-class.

Comment: Are you sure you wanted the increment `operator++` versus add `operator+`?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yes (why did I remove my comment? o.O) but that might be worth it -- depending on your preferences. It's a nested class, so it somehow makes sense (to me) to declare/define them inside the class body.

Comment: @KhouriGiordano yes ((I need it for a way to safely "rotate" around the enumone by one))

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thank you, but I would like to declare the enum & the functions in one place. (Maybe I'll move both out of class...)

Comment: @dyp how would the solution with friend functions look like?

Comment: @tatamas Sorry, I deleted the link: http://ideone.com/ySBEaa

Answer (score 1):

You can use global operator overloads to do this

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        enum MyEnum { CONSTA, CONSTB, CONSTC };
};

MyClass::MyEnum& operator++(MyClass::MyEnum& orig) { return ++orig; }
MyClass::MyEnum operator++(MyClass::MyEnum& orig, int) 
    { MyClass::MyEnum temp = orig++; return temp; }
```

See the compilable code [here please](http://ideone.com/YjKhnh).

Comment: Just making them friend functions would work as well.

Comment: @dyp I see no need, since `MyEnum` is public, and would render almost useless otherwise.

Comment: It's basically the argument Sean Parent uses: You can (ab)use friend functions to define functions inside the class.

Comment: @dyp Can you provide some link to enlighten me. I'm not so step up to   the current c++11 evangelists ;)

Comment: I think he mentioned it GoingNative 2013 - either in one of his two talks or at the Q&A panel. I'll try to find out exactly where I picked this up.

Comment: Ok, it's in the [first Q&A panel](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Interactive-Panel-Ask-Us-Anything), Sean Parent's answer to the question at 1:00:45 (although you might want to watch his second talk as well, for some context).

Comment: @dyp Yes, _"that's so clever"_ ;D Agreed.